# after uploading js file via cPanel, I find the js file turn blank when I go to wordpress plugin page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a problem with Wordpress plugin files.
I want to modify a plugin which was developed by someone else and I uploaded a Javascript file via the cPanel file manager to this plugin.
But when I go to the Wordpress plugin page to look up this file, it is blank.

I searched this online and found that it's probably need another step to hook this Javascript file to Wordpress, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Is the entire screen white or is there still some WordPress stuff displayed? Completely blank pages are often PHP errors.

Comment: Hi mcon thanks. But it's not a entire white. Just when I browse the plugins I installed, and when I want to see the code files of these plugins, I simply click them and the codes show up. But when I uploaded a new js file via cPanel and then I try to browse the js code, it's just nothing but white there.

Comment: It might be a problem with file permissions. Make sure you have them set correctly. WordPress has a a [page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) about it.